# Using a wrapper class for a typedef equivalent in Java; must I expose the class variable?

Tags: java, arraylist, typedef

I think I am missing something fundamental here. In writing an card-game app, I define a Card class, and then various collections of cards in this form:

```
ArrayList<Card> cards;
```

Now of course I can continue to use all the appropriate ArrayList methods.

At some point I get tired of writing ArrayList, and also need to create arrays of ArrayList so define a wrapper class like this:

```
class CardList { 
   protected ArrayList<Card> cards;
...overrides and class methods down here...
}
```

But now when I instantiate a CardList (say MyCardList), I have lost access to the underlying ArrayList methods, so it seems I have the choice of:

(a) exposing cards as a package-protected member, so I can then write MyCardList.cards.someArrayListMethod() OR

(b) or implementing passthrough methodsin CardList for every ArrayList method I want to use

Which is better, or am I hopelessly off track here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a package-scoped class like so:

```
class CardList extends ArrayList<Card> {
    // Literally no need for anything here unless you want
    // constructors that accept capacity, etc.; the default
    // constructor will be provided
}
```

...and then just use it:

```
CardList list = new CardList();
list.add(new Card());
// ...
```

---

But it's usually better to code to interfaces, in which case:

```
interface CardList extends List<Card> {
    // No need for anything here
}
```

and

```
class CardListImpl extends ArrayList<Card> implements CardList {
    // No need for anything here unless you want constructors
    // that accept capacity, etc.
}
```

and use it:

```
CardList list = new CardListImpl();
list.add(new Card());
// ...
```

...then you can switch to `LinkedList<Card>` if you like by just changing one file.

---

Or for that matter, you don't really need the `CardList` interface — `CardList` is only two characters shorter than `List<Card>`. So that would just be:

```
class CardListImpl extends ArrayList<Card> {
    // No need for anything here unless you want constructors
    // that accept capacity, etc.
}
```

and use it:

```
List<Card> list = new CardListImpl();
list.add(new Card());
// ...
```

...and again if you decide to switch the type of concrete list class, you only have to do that in one place.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding it right, I can now just access the list itself with this. ? I got confused about the need to create a member variable in there.

Comment: @Opus1217: Yup, that's what I'm showing with the "use it" code blocks. In a ***very*** hand-waving sense, `class CardList extends ArrayList<Card>` is a bit like a typedef... (It isn't, really, but you end up with something with that name that you can use.)

Comment: Looks great, and looks like I'm going to be able to clean up some messy code. I'll test it out to make sure I'm not missing anything and then accept. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Exposing cards directly is always a bad idea. If you need to access it, do it with a getter (public, protected or package protected as you need it to be) If you expose the field you risk a user setting it to null

You can delegate arraylist methods if you want, thought that would make more sense if you were combining several elements in your CardList

Another possibility is to extend ArrayList, but that would make sense only if there are particular functionality you want (for instance, you may want specific behaviour when adding a card that is already in the list)

A fourth possibility is to delegate only the methods you need, that makes you free to change the implementation (for instance, if every card is unique, you could use int or long to track the presence of each card instead of its presence in the list)